# Angular Js "Uncaught Error: No module: uiCropper" error on console

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hi i want to implement image cropper on my page. I found some code from [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Crackeraki/pen/avYNKP).I used the same code but the code is not working and it shows the below error[image]

```js
angular.module('app', ['uiCropper'])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myImage='';
    $scope.myCroppedImage='';

    var handleFileSelect=function(evt) {
      var file=evt.currentTarget.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (evt) {
        $scope.$apply(function($scope){
          $scope.myImage=evt.target.result;
        });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };
      angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change',handleFileSelect);
  });
```

```css
.cropArea {
  background: #E4E4E4;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <td>
    <div>Cropped Image:</div>
    <div><img ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}" /></div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="cropArea"><div ng-hide="myCroppedImage">Select an image file: <input type="file" id="fileInput" /></div>    
    <ui-cropper image="myImage" area-type="circle" chargement="'Loading'" result-image="myCroppedImage" canvas-scalemode="true"></ui-cropper>
    </div>
  </td>
</table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer the javascript , which you have not done with your code,

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/CrackerakiUA/ui-cropper/master/compile/unminified/ui-cropper.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not injecting the uiCropper js file in index.html. You have to include uiCropper js in index.html. Add this file t index.html and check.

```
<script src="http://rawgit.com/CrackerakiUA/ui-cropper/master/compile/unminified/ui-cropper.js"></script>
```